# C - Depth effect in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl

I read this tutorial online: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/. More precisely the chapter about projection matrices.

I am trying to apply what I read, to a specific part of what I drew. However I don't see anything different. Did I misunderstand anything or do I just apply it incorrectly?

I am actually drawing 2 houses. And I would like to create this effect: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/assets/images/tuto-3-matrix/homogeneous.png

My code:

```
       void rescale()
       {
         glViewport(0,0,500,500);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(-6.500, 6.500, -6.500, 6.500, -6.00, 12.00);
        }

        void setup()
        {
        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
         }

       void draw()
        {

    glPushMatrix();
          //draw something in the orthogonal projection
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    gluPerspective(0.0, 1, -12, 30);  //perspective projection
    glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(0.2,0.2,0.2);
        glTranslatef(-1, 0.5, -5);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        drawVertexCube();
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(0.2,0.2,0.2);
        glTranslatef(-1, 0.5, -40);
        glColor3f(0, 1.0, 0.0);
            drawVertexCube();
    glPopMatrix();
   glPopMatrix();

    glFlush(); 
        }
```

This is the result:

[image]

As you can see there is no (visible) result. I would like to accentuate the effect much more.

Comment: There are a lot of very old OpenGL tutorials out there. Try to use one does not use deprecated OpenGL1.0 functions

Answer (score 0):

Your `gluPerspective` call is invalid:

```
gluPerspective(0.0, 1, -12, 30);
```

The `near` and `far` parameters must both be positive, otherwise the command will generate just an GL error and will leave the current matrix unmodified, so your ortho projection is still in use. Your `glPushMatrix()`/`glPopMatrix()` calls won't help because you never enclosed the `glOrtho()` call in such a block, so you never restore to a state where that matrix is not already applied. Furthermore. the `glMatrixMode()` inbetween a `glLoadIdentity()` and  the `glOrtho` seems also quite weird.

You should also be aware that all GL matrix functions besides the `glLoad*` ones will *multiply* the current matrix by a new matrix. Since you still have the ortho matrix applied, you would get the product of both matrices, which will totally screw up your results.

Finally, you should be aware that *all* of the GL matrix strack functionality is *deprecated* and *completely removed* in the core profile of modern OpenGL. If you are learning OpenGL nowadays, you should really consider learning the "modern" way in OpenGL (which is basically already a decade old).